# Hibernate Second Level Cache, turning off by property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ehcache

What's is more important **spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache** or **@Cache** on Entity? I'm trying to disable second level cache by setting spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = false (my entities are still annotated with @Cache) and second level cache is still working ...
Is this expected behaviour ?

Comment: The `@Cache` annotations don't enable the actual functionality, so the 2nd level cache is staying enabled for a different reason (enabled through other means, you haven't actually set the correct property, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems like if dependencies are in classpath and "use_second_level_cache" is even false, Hibernate still uses some "NoOp" Region provider which still requires entities and their properties to be serializable,

After  turning off second level cache i was still getting NotSerializableException which is pretty confusing to me